# Don't see "Filter my contacts" under settings

Tags: contacts, lumia-925

I have a new Nokia Lumia 925 and want to filter out the contacts that came over from social media.  It says to go to settings-->Filter My Contacts however under settings I don't have that option.  Can anyone assist me with this issue?  Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, you *are* going to the Settings page of the People app, right? Not the global phone settings?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the **People** app
2. Open the app bar at the bottom and select **Settings**
3. Press **filter contact list**
4. Filter!